# How to print 2 barcodes that I generated separatly in 2 picture boxes on one page, one below the other?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, barcode-printing

I have created small winform app c# for generating barcodes in two separated picture boxes.
How can I print both barcodes from picture boxes on one page, one below the other?

[image]

```
private void btnGenerate1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string barcode = txtBarcode1.Text;

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(barcode.Length * 60, 110);
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))

        {
            Font oFont = new System.Drawing.Font("IDAutomationHC39M Free Version", 20);
            PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
            SolidBrush black = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            SolidBrush White = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            graphics.FillRectangle(White, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
            graphics.DrawString("*" + barcode + "*", oFont, black, point);

        }
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
            pictureBox1.Height = bitmap.Height;
            pictureBox1.Width = bitmap.Width;
        }
            }

         private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        if(printDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, 100, 500, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
```

[not alligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBDTN.jpg)

Comment: Can you please provide minimal sample code?

Comment: The drawing to a page is really the same as to a control. You already draw one image a 100,500. So next print the other below it!

Comment: yes it helped me , but how can I now allign them

Comment: I've posted [almost the exact same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49267169/blurry-and-large-image-barcode-being-generated-using-a-plugin-in-windows-form?answertab=active#tab-top) some day ago. Take a look at what I wrote there about the size of the Barcode and how the size is modified after the Barcode is created. As a note, `graphics.FillRectangle( (...) );` => `graphics.Clear(Color.White);`. Are you using that `MemoryStream` somewhere?